# RazorEngine - Namespace import compilation error

Tags: .net, razor, razorengine

I'm using the Razor Engine ([razorengine.codeplex.com](http://razorengine.codeplex.com)) in a non-MVC environment. I compile templates that are stored in files and use `@inherits` for intellisense support.

- RazorEngine Assembly
- Custom Assembly - references RazorEngine, contains `View<>` and sets `View<>` as baseclass
- Web application - references RazorEngine, Custom Assembly, contains .cshtml template files

All cshtml files have the following `@inherits` directive:

```
@inherits View<SomeModel>
```

An error is thrown:

> The type of namespace View isn't found, are you missing an assembly reference?

My web.config contains the following entry:

```
<add namespace="CustomAssembly.NamespaceContainingViewClass" />
```

**I think this has something to do with the other entry `<assemblies>`, where my `CustomAssembly` isn't mentioned. Is this the case? Can I compile with my custom base class which is contained in another assembly?**

*p.s. I cannot retrieve a strong name for the assembly because my custom assembly references a 3d party assembly which isn't strongly named either...*

Stacktrace:

```
at RazorEngine.Compilation.DirectCompilerServiceBase.CompileType(TypeContext context)
at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplate(String template, Type modelType)
at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.GetTemplate(String template, Type modelType, String name)
at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.Compile(String template, Type modelType, String name)
at RazorEngine.Razor.Compile(String template, Type modelType, String name)
```

Comment: Where is this error thrown? What's the stack trace?

Comment: The error is thrown when I call `Razor.Compile` with arguments (one of which is the templatestring containing `@inherits`). I've added the stacktrace to the question above.

Comment: Does it work when you have the fully qualified name after @inherits. It might be that MVC does some extra work to get the namespaces to work. Also did you try and add the namespace in the template itself with @using MyNamespace;

Comment: Yes it does work with full name. I personally think that the `<assemblies>` entry needs to be provided also however this is not possible due to strong naming. I have no publickeytoken to provide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add the razor config section to your `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="razorEngine" type="RazorEngine.Configuration.RazorEngineConfigurationSection, RazorEngine" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
</configuration>

<razorEngine>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="CustomAssembly.NamespaceContainingViewClass" />
    </namespaces>
</razorEngine>
```

Comment: I added it to my folder containing the views: `/layout/razor_views/web.config` without any success...

Comment: It should be in the main `web.config` or `app.config`

Comment: This project has long gone through many changes. Please see the github project https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

Answer (score 7):

You can add a namespace in the TemplateServiceConfiguration:

```
    TemplateServiceConfiguration templateConfig = new TemplateServiceConfiguration();
    templateConfig.Namespaces.Add("MyNamespaceGoesHere"); 
    templateConfig.Resolver = new DelegateTemplateResolver(name =>
    {
       <My template resolve implementation>
    }
    Razor.SetTemplateService(new TemplateService(templateConfig));
    using (TextWriter tw = new StringWriter())
    {
      Razor.Resolve(viewName + ".cshtml", model).Run(new ExecuteContext(), tw);
      var emailHtmlBody = tw.ToString();
    }
```